# How can I skip over symbols in elisp?

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax, elisp

While skipping over spaces works fine using

```
(skip-chars-forward "\s-")
```

I can't seem to be able to skip over symbols using

```
(skip-chars-forward "\s_")
```

Maybe I am using she command wrongly, and it somehow recovers in the 1st case?

The relevant documentation does not seem to answer the question:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `(skip-syntax-forward "w_")`, which skips over both word and symbol characters.

If you want to match syntax classes in a *regexp* written as a string, for passing to functions like `search-regexp-forward`, you will need to double your backslashes: `"\\s-"`.  But the argument to `skip-syntax-forward` is not a regexp, just a string in which each character represents a syntax class.

Comment: Strangely enough, I do want (skip-syntax-forward "_") :) Thanks for your helpful answer!

Comment: I am sorry for the mistaken assumption, but glad that it was helpful anyway!

Comment: By the way, it looks like the reason your original `(skip-chars-forward "\s-")` works is that `\s`, as a string or character escape, represents the space character.  I did not know that until just now.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax symbols as taken be search-forms aren't usable from skip-forms. Use `skip-syntax-...`

```
(skip-syntax-forward "_")
```

Or use an own sets of chars to move

```
(setq "my-choice" "[[:alnum:]].")
```

Evaluating form below after `")"` should jump behind `"...."`

```
(skip-chars-forward my-choice)asdf....
```

Alternatively, using [Emacs Werkstatt](https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/+download): <kbd>M-x ar-symbol- TAB</kbd> displays a whole bunch of commands working on symbols: forward, backward, delete, copy, hide... etc

BTW, the reason why `skip-chars` doesn't take syntax is, probably, speed.
Skip-chars is very fast, reading and translating syntax tables probably would slow it down.

Comment: The actual way to call the command appears to be (skip-syntax-forward "_"), which I inferred from Jon O.'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the command wrong, it should be:

```
(skip-chars-forward " \n\t")
(skip-chars-forward "A-Z_a-z-0-9")
```

Whatever you put in the string gets put into `[]` regex construct,
and it doesn't expand `\\s-`.

Comment: The second one doesn't seem right, it skips whitespace and _:s. The OP asked for symbol characters and _:s.

Comment: as I understood, he meant `_` as a symbol, which it is.

Comment: Yes, but he wants to skip symbols, i.e. all characters that could be part of a symbol. Like, `(skip-chars-forward "a-zA-Z0-9_")`, but with the exact set of characters defined by the syntax table. Your code will skip whitespace and _:s only.

Comment: I see, `\\s_` means symbol.